# use CGRectMake to make a full screen rectangle

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to use CGRectMake to make a full screen rectangle. How would I set the width and the height to the size of the screen? That way the whole rectangle would take up the screen...

Comment: Do you mean _full screen rectangle_? _Triangle_ makes no sense. You need not `CGRectMake`. Take a look at `UIScreen` or `NSScreen` to get screen rectangles.

Comment: yah, I mean rectangles, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the rectangle should be exactly as big as the screen (not considering UINavigationController, UITabBarController and safe area), you should use *[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds*